# Are type guards the only circumstance that TypeScript is able to determine different types for the same variable in different parts of the code?

Tags: typescript, typeguards

My question relates to this question:

[How to implement "If not interface, add necessary properties to match"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71687386/how-to-implement-if-not-interface-add-necessary-properties-to-match)

I've answered the question, and essentially the mental model I have is that:

> TypeScript has a one to one mapping of variables to types, and isn't able to track 'the type of this variable A at line 1 is ... and the type of variable A at line 5 is ...'.

But of course, this isn't strictly true, with type guards TypeScript does exactly this.

```
function usesSomeType(value: string | number) {


    value; //(parameter) value: string | number

    if (typeof value === 'string') {
        value; //(parameter) value: string

        // TypeScript knows that the type of value is different on lines 4 and on lines 9. 
    }

}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=12&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABCAzgUxQZTgWzQFQE8AHNACgDcBDAGxDQC5EUoAnGMAc0QB9EwQOAEZpWASkQBvAFCzE8xNTpoA3IgD06ssSqsqeKKIlL6TFuy69+gkazkKYwRGSgk0cJybSIAvH8QA5OYcnAESMgqRirT0aprauvpohuLRymZsIfZRGuqIRKSYEOzEUIgA1mBwAO4oiFAAFlRljd6upIgeafSIMHUAJo7AomhgZQiINBwYiAAsiFRg-Z1IU2AzAJwAdIjSkQC+svtAA)

My question is - are type guards the only circumstance that TypeScript has this behaviour, or are there other circumstances?

Comment: There are [assertion functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions), like I mentioned in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71714591/2887218) to the other question. The general phenomenon is *control flow analysis*, which happens via various type guards, user defined type guards functions, and assertion functions. It's mostly all documented [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html).

Comment: @jcalz I think your comment warrants an answer itself. That list of all the circumstances that does the narrowing is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

this is another way i know of

```
enum objTypes {
  TYPE1 = 1,
  TYPE2 = 2
} 

class Object1 {
  objType: objTypes.TYPE1 = objTypes.TYPE1;
  x?: number;
}

class Object2 {
  objType: objTypes.TYPE2 = objTypes.TYPE2;
  y?: number;
} 

function useSomeFoo(bar: Object1 | Object2) {
  if (bar.objType === objTypes.TYPE1) {
    bar.x // accessible, no error.
    // bar.y // error
  }
}
```

Comment: But that's just a type guard right. Same scenario.